# How to use datatables.net-vue3 in visual studio that use vuejs3?

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, .net-core, npm-install, datatables-1.10

How can I use datatables.net-vue3 with in vuejs3 and visual studio?
I installed it via node like this
[image]

It is not working, all import in visual studio I do it this way

[image]

This imports are not working for me
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to install the [core datatables package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/datatables.net) manually (currently, you have vue and bootstrap bindings and select 2 bootstrap plugin). Try:

```
npm i datatables.net
```

and then import the main component from there:

```
import DataTable from 'datatables.net'
```